# Recommend a good font management software for Windows 7

Tags: software-recommendation, font-management, windows

I am looking for a good **Font Mangement Software** for Windows 7.

Can you guys please recommend a good professional one, something that has **options like**:

- install/uninstall a font at the touch of a click
- lets you preview the typeface when you select it
- install all the fonts in one folder and uninstall them after you're done with them
- something with as many options as possible but yet simple to use, user-friendly
- possibly something that recommends similar typefaces (that's utopia already...but maybe..:)

Ideally would be a free software, but I have a feeling there isn't one, so if you don't know about a free one, recommend what you know as great professional software you have used and works great.

If you can, **please include screen-shots** in your answer or links to see as much as possible about the software. I don't want to install 10 and choose, I want to choose and install 1-3 and decide what is the one that works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend Nexus Font Manager, [Nexus site here](http://www.xiles.net/), it's great for a beginner and I use this frequently - especially from a USB stick - pretty useful.

I'm not affiliated with the firm, but am a satisfied user of it, and would recommend it if you want a useful font manager that does the job.

It's a small learning curve, but not too bad (and saved me having to install a lot of fonts into C:/Windows/Fonts - which can only be a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

"The Font Thing" by Susan Fisher was my weapon of choice for Win XP. Sadly it doesn't work for me anymore.

[Nexus Font](http://xiles.net/) is what I use now. Haven't played much with it so far, but multiline, custom color and sharpness settings are enough for me to love it (so far). My personal recommendation.

Comment: Hey, looks great! And its Free:) I'll give it a try and post some feedback here :)

Comment: @FlaviusFrantz The only really annoying thing with NexusFont is that I don't understand how to change the root folder. I still have to go through my large - but gladly perfectly sorted - archive in the file explorer window, install it and then access it. Btw: Upvoting appreciated :)

Comment: Yes - NexusFont is great. A couple more features e.g. the option to display one fonts by family rather than individually, would make it a killer.

Comment: But nexus Font unfortunately doesn't scan the folder (I must point it directly to the font) and doesn't support drag&drop installing fonts...

Answer (score 2):

Suitcase Fusion 5 is a good all-around font management program, and plays well with both Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks and Windows 8.

It also allows you to sort by font type (serif, slab, etc.); customize font sets, and preview font pairings.

Suitcase also automatically activates plug-ins for professional applications like Adobe CS6 and Microsoft Office.

http://www.extensis.com/font-management/suitcase-fusion/

Answer (score 0):

Google showed this:

http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-font-manager.htm

Not sure if its exactly what you're after but it looks promising.

Comment: thx. I'll try it and add some feedback