# Type specimen generator

Tags: typography, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a software that would allow me to test a big amount of fonts by producing one page (or at least, one paragraph) of text for each font in a folder.

I'm not looking for a simple sample phrase nor a full fontset, but for a whole paragraph at least, in order to look at kerning and greyness and be able to compare each font. I have tried Font View, but it cant produce a whole paragraph.
By the way, fonts are Type 1 and OTF;

Edit: …and I run a Windows 8.1 64 bits.

Comment: If you're looking for software you may want to ask in http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Almost any font manager has the ability to print specimens. The manager I use, FontAgentPro, allows you to print a lorem ipsum paragraph of any font or multiple fonts.

Comment: Ok, thanks Scott, but it seems this software runs only under Mac OS and I forgot to mention I'm looking for a Windows software.

Comment: As I posted almost *any* font manager will do this. What app you need for your OS is up to you.

Comment: I took a look at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/recommend-a-good-font-management-software-for-windows-7/ but NexusFont seems not to be able to do so, like AMP Fontview, the specimen text is size limited.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/impallari/font-testing-page
Demo: http://www.impallari.com/testing/

The Font Testing Page is a tool primarily intended for type designers and independent foundries to 'Drag and Drop' their work in progress into a browser. It can also be used by art directors, graphic designers, teachers and students interested in seeing how a typeface works on the web.

There is a short video demonstrating this tool, http://vimeo.com/40296571

Operation is simple:

Drag the font you want to try to the upper area of the Testing Page.
Add more fonts and you'll see their file names and file sizes as buttons

Comment: Thanks, seems great, but as I bought an old Bitstream font CD, I have nothing less than 3000 styles to test: so I'm looking for an automated task. Here, I have to choose the font, look at the text page, etc. But I keep it for the later test phase.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tried Bitstream Font Navigator, which is discontinued but could be found bundled with Corel Draw trial, and seems to be usable with no trial limit.

It does exactly what I asked for.